# Where can I store JWT tokens in Unity mobile app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, jwt

I'm looking for the best solution to store access and refresh JWT tokens (in Unity Android mobile app), which I receive from server.
I can save it in a player prefs, asset bundles or smartphone memory, but which solution will be safer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PlayerPrefs` is solution you are looking for.
It is kind of generic solution for iOS and Android and it is alternative to `SharedPreferences` in Android and `Keychain` in iOS. If you need encryption then you can implement a wrapper which will encrypt on saving and decrypt on loading.

Comment: Is it safe to use? Do I need to set special settings for PlayerPrefs?

Comment: It has no encryption but you can easily write your own wrapper which will encrypt on saving and decrypt on loading. We follow this way in commercial projects. You can find implementation in the internet.

Comment: Спасибо, Игорь!) Thank you.

Comment: Just a notice: PlayerPrefs saves to the registry on Windows. Might want to keep that in mind.